# Как задать реакцию на изменение текста в edittext?

Tags: java, android

У меня в при открытии активити создаётся метод, реагирующий на изменения текста в edittext, и реагирует на это правильно. Есть кнопка, которая должна изменять изменять текст в textview, но так как текст в этом textview задан с помощью метода edittext ChangedListener, то почему то она его не меняет.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);            
        final EditText edittext1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        final TextView tvKof = findViewById(R.id.tvKof);           
        edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tvKof.setText("5");
            }
        });
}

public void Clear1 (View v){
    TextView tvKof = findViewById(R.id.tvKof);
    tvKof.setText("0");
    }
```

Comment: Потому что ссылку на ваш TextView нужно вынести в поле класса, а не обращаться к нему через локальные переменные методов. Так же в Java есть конвенция по написанию кода, которой рекомендуется придерживаться разработчикам, чтобы у других разработчиков не шла кровь из глаз, в частности, имена методов в Java принято писать с маленькой буквы.

Comment: TextView tvKof = findViewById(R.id.tvKof); я вынес ссылку в поле класса и убрал инициализацию этого textview из методов. Теперь приложение не открывается. Что я сделал не правильно?

Comment: @Олег , инициализацию в onCreate()  делайте ( tvKof = findViewById(R.id.tvKof);) а в поле класса : TextView tvKof;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText edittext1;
    TextView tvKov;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edittext1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        tvKov = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tvKov.setText("5");
            }
        });


    }


    public void Clear1(View view) {
        tvKov.setText("0");
    }
}
```